# Show that $\int h_n'(x) \varphi(x)\, dx \to \langle \delta, \varphi\rangle$ - Generalized functions theory

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In the book *Partial Differential Equations* by Robert Strichartz, there's an exercise (#$1$, page $9$) that I am not quite sure how to solve. Is there anyone could give me the principal steps how to solve it?

**Problem :** Let $H$ be the distribution in $\mathbb{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ defined by the Heaviside function

$$ H(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    1      & x>0\\
    0 & x \leq 0\\
  \end{cases}
$$

Show that if $h_n$ are differentiable functions such that $\int h_n \varphi(x) dx \to <H, \varphi>$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $\varphi \in \mathbb{D}$, then $$\int h_n'(x) \varphi(x)\, dx \to \langle \delta, \varphi\rangle.$$

Comment: I hazarded a couple of guesses as to what you intended in the mathematical notation in your title, since it was something of a mess.  Your question remains not altogether clear unless one looks at the book. You should try to make it more self-contained. $\qquad$

Comment: Specifically, where it said $\int h_n`(x) \phi(x) dx to <\delta, \phi>$, I changed it to $\int h_n'(x) \varphi(x)\, dx \to \langle \delta, \varphi\rangle$. $\qquad$

Comment: I feel like there is a typo in the last expression. Should $h_n$ be unprimed?

Comment: choose $\varphi$ such that integrating by part is a good idea

Comment: Hint: What does convergence in distribution mean exactly? Also, integrate by parts.

Comment: @Moya : I'm quite sure he doesn't know the convergence in distribution, nor the functional analysis, such as the facts about densely defined operators

Comment: hint for choosing $\varphi$ :  what can you say on $\varphi'$ ?

Comment: I don't know what book of Strichartz you are referring to, but your link points to a book by Walter Strauss.

Comment: Wow, my bad... I'll modify it

Comment: so what do you get by integrating by parts... come on. wake up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts we get:

$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty h_n ' (x) \varphi (x) \ \textrm d x = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \left( h_n \varphi \Bigg|_{-\infty} ^\infty - \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty h_n (x) \varphi' (x) \ \textrm d x \right) = \\
\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \left( (0 - 0) - \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty h_n (x) \varphi' (x) \ \textrm d x \right) = - \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \langle h_n, \varphi' \rangle = - \langle H, \varphi' \rangle = - \int \limits _0 ^\infty \varphi' (x) \ \textrm d x = \\
-\big( \varphi (\infty) - \varphi (0) \big) = \varphi (0) = \langle \delta, \varphi \rangle ,$$

which shows that $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} h_n ' = \delta$ (in the sense of distributions).

(Above, I have used twice that $\varphi (\infty) = \varphi (-\infty) = 0$, because $\varphi$ has compact support, which means that $\varphi$ is $0$ towards $\pm \infty$.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I appreciate! Try next time to give a fair idea of how to solve the problem. Something like compact support was sufficient in my opinion.

Comment: The argument of compact support is clever, because we know that all test functions have got vanish outside a bound subset of $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, then it is straightforward that $\lim_{x \to \infty, -\infty} \varphi(x)=0$